# How to slice list left and right, except middle part?

Tags: python, list, slice

List:

```
x = [1, 6, 2, 7, 1, 6, 1]

len(x)
> 7
```

How would I split the list for the first 3 and last 3, thus value 7 is left alone using list slicing methods?

Output

```
x[0:2,4:6] #<-- This doesn't work
> [1, 6, 2, 1, 6, 1] #<-- Expected output
```

Comment: For example:  x=x[:3]+x[4:]

Comment: @kantal Is there a way to just keep it same brackets? `x[...,...]` similar to this one?

Comment: And what about it: del x[3:-3]

Comment: That's a list, not an array.

Comment: Just concatenate the two halves: `x[:3] +x[-3:]`.

Comment: @AndreasDeak Yea I guess it's the better approach

Comment: I just noticed @kantal's concatenation and `del` solutions above. It doesn't get better than that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Meeting OP requeriment: "Is there a way to just keep it same brackets? x[...,...] similar to this one? " (not just using `x[:3]+x[-3:]`):

Use `numpy.delete` together with `numpy.r_`. Specify which first number of elements `n1` and which last number of elements `n2` you want to keep this way

```
import numpy as np
x = [1, 6, 2, 7, 1, 6, 1]
n1 = 3 # Keep first n1 elements
n2 = 3 # Keep last n2 elements

print(list(np.delete(x,(np.r_[n1:len(x)-n2])))) # [1 6 2 1 6 1]
```

Comment: Numpy answer on a native python question. Almost always overkill.

Comment: It meets OP request: "Is there a way to just keep it same brackets? x[...,...] similar to this one? "  I think under this specific request is not an overkill.

Comment: Also the downvote is specified for non useful answers, which I do not think this is one.

Comment: The result isn't even a list which OP wants. Importing numpy for a trivial list operation is overkill by definition. Same as importing pandas just to parse a simple csv. It's not a useful answer in my opinion. Just because OP wants a single pair of brackets is not reason enough to write poor code.

Comment: Changed the object-type issue. How would you do it like OP requests then?

Comment: Like [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53680150/how-to-slice-list-left-and-right-except-middle-part#comment94217866_53680150), posted half an hour ago.

Comment: Fair, but this is just another way. Also good to know both these numpy functions. I will keep the answer up anyway.

Answer (score -1):

You could do: x[0:3]+x[4:7] or  x[:3]+x[-3:]. The second one gets the first 3 elements from the last and the first three elements from the right.